# Expanding searchbar - keep expanded state if text is entered

Tags: javascript, html, css

Working on a searchbar that has a default collapsed state and, when clicked, expands with an animation, and collapses again when it is no longer focused.

How do I make it so that when you have entered some text into the search field, and you click outside of the input, the searchbar maintains its expanded state if text is present?

```css
body {
  color: #666;
  font: 90%/180% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}


/* Demo 2 */

#demo-2 input[type=search] {
  width: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}

#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `:valid` selector and `minlength` and `required` attribute.

```css
body {
  color: #666;
  font: 90%/180% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

input {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}

input::-webkit-search-decoration,
input::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  display: none;
}

input[type=search] {
  background: #ededed url(https://static.tumblr.com/ftv85bp/MIXmud4tx/search-icon.png) no-repeat 9px center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 9px 10px 9px 32px;
  width: 55px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10em;
  -moz-border-radius: 10em;
  border-radius: 10em;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #66CC75;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(109, 207, 246, .5);
}

input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999;
}


/* Demo 2 */

#demo-2 input[type=search] {
  width: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search]:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#demo-2 input[type=search]:valid, /* added */
#demo-2 input[type=search]:focus {
  width: 130px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: auto;
}

#demo-2 input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#demo-2 input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<form id="demo-2">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" minlength="1" required>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a js solution because they need to target inputs containers and can't use `:focus` `:valid` and such css elements, here is a solution (css not done)

```js
const events = () => {
  document.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.closest('input')) {
      event.target.closest('.field').classList.add('open');
    } else {
      document.querySelectorAll('.field').forEach(el => { 
        if (el.querySelector('input').value.length == 0) {
          el.classList.remove('open');
        }
      })
    }
  }) 
} 

events();
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
</form>
```